# Program crashes on exit qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I added `QApplication::quit();` to two if statements so that when the user clicks 'cancel' or 'x' the program ends; However once cancel or x is clicked the program crashes and it says there is something wrong with the program. I'm not sure why it keeps crashing. I added this code in the main.cpp file.

Header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QString>

class SentenceProcessor {
  public:
    int getWordNumber(QString sentence);
    int getVowelNumber(QString sentence);
    bool isReversible(QString sentence);
    QString wordsReversed(QString sentence);
    QString formatSentence(QString sentence);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>

int SentenceProcessor::getWordNumber(QString sentence) {
  QStringList list = sentence.split(" ");
  int len = 0;
  foreach(QString str, list) {
    len++;
  }
  return len;
}

int SentenceProcessor::getVowelNumber(QString sentence) {
  int count = 0;
  int len = sentence.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (sentence.data()[i] == 'a' || sentence.data()[i] == 'A' || sentence.data()[i] == 'e' || sentence.data()[i] == 'E' || sentence.data()[i] == 'i' ||
      sentence.data()[i] == 'I' || sentence.data()[i] == 'o' || sentence.data()[i] == 'O' || sentence.data()[i] == 'u' || sentence.data()[i] == 'U') {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;

}

bool SentenceProcessor::isReversible(QString sentence) {
  QStringList list1 = sentence.split(" ");
  QStringList list2;
  int count = 0;
  bool reversible;
  foreach(QString str, list1) {
    list2.prepend(str);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    if (QString::compare(list1[i], list2[i], Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (count == list1.size()) {
    reversible = true;
  } else {
    reversible = false;
  }
  return reversible;
}

QString SentenceProcessor::wordsReversed(QString sentence) {
  QStringList list1 = sentence.split(" ");
  QStringList list2;
  foreach(QString str, list1) {
    list2.prepend(str);
  }
  QString reversed = list2.join(" ");

  return reversed;
}

QString SentenceProcessor::formatSentence(QString sentence) {
  sentence.data()[0] = sentence.data()[0].toUpper();
  int len = sentence.length();
  if (sentence.data()[len - 1] != '.') {
    sentence.append('.');
  }
  return sentence;
}
```

Main.cpp file for testing:
In this file is where I added `QApplication::quit();`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QMessageBox::StandardButton response;
  response = QMessageBox::question(0, "Ready for input", "Are you ready to enter a sentence?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

  while (response == QMessageBox::Yes) {
    SentenceProcessor s1;
    bool ok;
    QString text = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Sentence Processor", "Enter sentence", QLineEdit::Normal, 0, &ok);
    QStringList list = text.split(" ");

    if (ok) {
      while (list.size() < 2) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", "You need to enter at least two words");
        text = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Sentence Processor", "Enter sentence", QLineEdit::Normal, 0, &ok);
        if (!ok) {
            QApplication::quit();
        }else{
             list = text.split(" ");
        }
      }

      QString numWords = QString::number(s1.getWordNumber(text));
      QString numVowels = QString::number(s1.getVowelNumber(text));
      bool reversible = s1.isReversible(text);
      QString wordsReverse = s1.wordsReversed(text);
      QString senFormat = s1.formatSentence(text);
      QString reversibleText;
      if (reversible == false) {
        reversibleText = "Your sentence is not reversible";
      } else {
        reversibleText = "Your sentence is reversible";
      }

      QMessageBox::information(0, "Sentence Processing", "Your sentence: " + text + "\n" +
        "The number of words in your sentence is: " + numWords + "\n The number of vowels in your sentence: " +
        numVowels + "\n" + reversibleText + "\n" + "Your sentence reversed is: " + wordsReverse + "\n" +
        "Your sentence formatted is: " + senFormat);

      response = QMessageBox::question(0, "Another Input", "Would you like to enter another sentence?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    }else{
        QApplication::quit();
   }
  }
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: To much code. Build the project with the address sanitizer.

Comment: Build this in debug mode and use debugger to find out on which line the code crashes. I tried it and the code does not crash for me. It ends in inifinite loop of message boxes but it does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your crash is probably that you use `QApplication::quit();` in the middle of your code, even before the application `exec()` gets called. It looks like you assume that `quit()` is the exit point of your function. It is not. Only `return` or the end of scope is the exit point from any function, including `main()`. You should use `return` (and return 0 or some error code such as 1 or -1, it is up to you) instead all of your calls of `QApplication::quit()`, then it may work as you would expect.

Since you are not actually using application event loop, you should probably remove `app.exec();`. Just use `return 0;` instead. With `app.exec()` your application will never finish.

Btw, this way of designing your Qt code is wrong. You should ideally execute your code when application's event loop is running. Which starts when you call `exec()`. But given the fact that the message boxes have their own event loops, your code might actually work in the end. But it is definitely a wrong way of doing Qt apps. Overall, you should study what event loop in Qt application is and how it works. Your code looks like you have no clue.

Comment: *"QApplication::quit(); in the middle of your code, even before the application exec() gets called"*, actually, this is not directly a problem, the call just does nothing. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit (quit is same as `exit(0)` ).

Comment: @hyde Yeah, very true. I did not explore what was happening in the code after `QApplication::quit()` was called, I assumed that it ran into some unexpected state and crashed due to some overflow, invalid index or something like that. Anyway, it was obvious for me that the OP expects that the `quit()` is the exit point, which is wrong... Now I tested the program and it only ends in infinite loop of message boxes. No crash occurred for me, which is strange. Anyway, I am pretty sure that using `return 0` instead of `QApplication::quit()` and removing `app.exec()` would solve his issues.